# Meteor Tutorial - Tracker is not defined

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ionic, meteor

Estoy siguiendo el tutorial de Meteor con Ionic y aunque he ido solventando algún que otro bug que tiene me he quedado atascado en uno en concreto que no sé por donde meterle mano. En concreto ha sido al modificar el main.ts con este código

```
import 'meteor-client';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'; import { MeteorObservable } from 'meteor-rxjs'; import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor'; import { AppModule } from './app.module';

Meteor.startup(() => {   const subscription = MeteorObservable.autorun().subscribe(() => {

    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(() => subscription.unsubscribe());
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);   }); });
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente

> ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined
>       at autorun (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:178469:13)
>       at Observable._subscribe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:178480:27)
>       at Observable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23023:25)
>       at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:23011:93)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:57:65
>       at maybeReady (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123856:57)
>       at HTMLDocument.loadingCompleted (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:123868:9)
>       at t.invokeTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:15660)
>       at r.runTask (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:10834)
>       at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:8100/build/polyfills.js:3:16794)

En principio no creo que necesite ninguna dependencia más puesto que tampoco veo que pida nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se solucionó actualizando la versión de NodeJs a la 8.1